# Monotonicity of solution of very simple integral equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Given p>1 denote by x=x(p) the solution of 
$$
\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^p}=1.
$$
Prove that $p\to x(p)$ is a decreasing function of $p$ on $(1,\infty)$

Comment: yes, please give us at least some motivation!

Comment: Did you try the implicit function theorem?

Comment: The motivation comes from the fact that $x(p)=\tan_p(1)$, where $\tan_p$ denotes so called generalized tangent.  I believe that $p\to\tan_p(y)$ is decreasing for each $y\in[0,1]$.  The case $y=1$ seems the most difficult of them (the problem is easy for $y\in[0,\log(2)]$).

Comment: About implicit function theorem: yes, if we differentiate the problem is reduced to the following:  suppose $x_*>1$ is the solution of $$\int_0^{x_*}\frac{t^p\log(t)dt}{(1+t^p)^2}=0$$ and $x_{**}$ is the solution of $$\int_0^{x_{**}}\frac{dt}{1+t^p}=1.$$  We need to show that $x_{**}\leq x_*$

Comment: Or that $$\int_0^{x_{**}} \frac{t^p log(t)}{(1+t^p)^2} < 0$$ which might be easier.

Comment: Yes, this is equivalent. I am not sure this is any easier though since the definition of $x_{**}$ anyway involves the second equation. Thanks for the comment anyway!

Comment: I think it's simpler in that you don't really know what $x_{**}$ is and you don't really know what $x_*$ is, but not knowing one thing is better than not knowing two.

Comment: Anyway, the solution is 5 lines long and takes 20 minutes to find (I posted it on AoPS). I wonder what are the corresponding parameters for those who voted to close. Should be at least as good as mine because I find it prudent to abstain from declaring something I cannot do in half an hour "not research level"...

Comment: Fedja, thanks for posting your ingenious solution!